# At least one value required in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am building a form using `ReactiveFormsModule`.

I need the user to input contact details:

- home phone number
- mobile phone number
- email

The form should be valid, if either home or mobile phone number is entered, that means **AT LEAST ONE** is required. Email is optional.

```
this.contact = this.fb.group({
    'Festnetz': [],
    'Mobil': [],
    'Email': [],
});

this.contact.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
    console.log(form, this.contact.status);
});
```

How to declare that using `FormBuilder`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
        this.contact = this.fb.group({
        'Festnetz': [],
        'Mobil': [],
        'Email': [],
    },{validator:(formGroup:FormGroup)=>{
return this.validatePhone(formgroup);

    });

validatePhone(formgroup:FormGroup){
     if(formgroup.controls["Festnetz"].value || formgroup.controls["phone"].value){
            return {validatePhone:true};
            }
            else{
            return null;
            }
    }
```

OR you can create a separate group for your phone numbers:

```
    this.contact = this.fb.group({
    'phoneGroup':this.fb.group({
       'Festnetz': [],
            'Mobil': []
    },{validator:(formgroup:FormGroup)=>{
       return this.validatePhone(formGroup);

        }),
            'Email': [],
        });

validatePhone(formgroup:FormGroup){
 if(formgroup.controls["Festnetz"].value || formgroup.controls["phone"].value){
        return {validatePhone:true};
        }
        else{
        return null;
        }
}
```

NOTE:I am assuming 'Festnetz' is one of the phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can change the status of your form and/or control errors within the observable you created.

For example:

```
this.contact = this.fb.group({
'Festnetz': [],
'Mobil': [],
'Email': [],
});

this.contact.setErrors({required: true});
this.contact.valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
    if(newValue.Festnetz.length > 0 || newValue.Mobil.length > 0){
        this.contact.setErrors(null);
    } else {
        this.contact.setErrors({required: true});
    } 
});
```

Then just replace the **length > 0** validation for whatever suits your purpose such as a nested loop to confirm the length >= 7 or set `newValue.Festnetz.setErrors({minlength: true});`